$E h(X_n,Y_n)\rightarrow E h(X,Y)\forall h\in C_b(\mathbf{R}^2)\iff E f(X_n)g(Y_n)\rightarrow E f(X)g(Y)\forall f,g\in C_b(\mathbf{R})$
I want to show that $\mathbb{E} h(X_n,Y_n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E} h(X,Y)$ for any bounded continuous function $h\in\mathcal{C}_b(\mathbf{R}^2)$. Show that it suffices to show this for $h(x,y)$ of the form $f(x)g(y)$ with $f$ and $g$ bounded and continuous. As a remark, the above is the definition of convergence in law of $(X_n,Y_n)$ towards $(X,Y)$.
So, my idea was to use a density result, if it is the case. I thought of proving that $$\mathcal{C}_b(\mathbf{R})\otimes\mathcal{C}_b(\mathbf{R})\text{ is dense in }\mathcal{C}_b(\mathbf{R}^2)$$Now, some problems arise such as compacity of $\mathbf{R}^2$, the norm we are using related to the (possible) density result above. Any advice towards solving this would be appreciated.
The hint for the equivalence given in the title was to use Stone-Weierstrass and the fact that if $E[f(X_n)]\rightarrow E[f(X)]$ for any $f$ in a class of functions s.t. the family of all  linear combinations of its elements is dense in $C_0(\mathbf{R})$, then $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$

An easy way out is to take $f(x)=e^{it\cdot x}$ and $g(x)=e^{is\cdot x}$. Then the condition implies that the joint characteristic function converges for arbitrary $s,t\in\Bbb{R}$. That is enough for joint convergence in distribution(law)
That is, we say $$(X_{n},Y_{n})\xrightarrow{d}(X,Y)\iff E[e^{itX_{n}+isY_{n}}]\to E[e^{itX+isY}]$$ for any $s,t\in\Bbb{R}$.
The direction you are thinking in is not true though. See here

If you want to go in the Stone-Weirestrass theorem approach, I'll sketch the method here.
First fix an arbitrary compact set in $\Bbb{R}^{2}$ say $A$. Let $\mu_{n}$ (resp $\mu$) denote the joint distribution in $\Bbb{R}^{2}$ for $(X_{n},Y_{n})$ (resp $(X,Y)$).
Now, for this compact box, if you take $h(x,y)=x^{n}y^{m}$, then by the condition, you have $\int_{A}x^{n}y^{m}\,d\mu_{n}\to\int_{A}x^{n}y^{m}\,d\mu$ and hence by linearity, for any polynomial $p(x,y)$, you have
$$\int_{A}p(x,y)\,d\mu_{n}\to \int_{A}p(x,y)\,d\mu$$
Now for any continuous function $f$ supported in $A$, by Stone-Weirestrass theorem, find a sequence of polynomials $p_{m}(x,y)$ which converges to $f$ in the supremum norm.
You get by by applying DCT, \begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{A}f(x,y)\,d\mu_{n}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{A}\lim_{m\to\infty}p_{m}(x,y)\,d\mu_{n}\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{A}p_{m}(x,y)\,d\mu_{n}\\
&=\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_{A}p_{m}(x,y)d\mu\\
&=\int_{A}\lim_{m\to\infty}p_{m}(x,y)\,d\mu=\int_{A}f(x,y)\,d\mu\end{align}
This works for any arbitrary compact set $A$. Thus, for all compactly supported continuous functions $f$, you have that $$\int_{\Bbb{R}^{2}}f(x,y)\,d\mu_{n}\to\int_{\Bbb{R}^{2}}f(x,y)\,d\mu$$
This is enough to show that $(X_{n},Y_{n})\xrightarrow{d} (X,Y)$ as we apriori know that $(X,Y)$ is a bonafide probability distribution.
One can jump from compactly supported function to showing that the joint cdf converges to the joint cdf of $(X,Y)$ by means of using smooth bump functions.
NOTE For showing convergence convergence in distribution of $X_{n}\to X$, if $X$ is a random variable, it is enough to show that $E(f(X_{n}))\to E(f(X))$ for all compactly supported functions $f$.
It is when the limiting measure is not a probability distrbution is when the method breaks down. For example, if $X_{n}$ is defined such that $P(X_{n}=k)=\frac{1}{n}$ for $k=1,2,...,n$. Then, for any compactly supported function $f$, you have $\lim_{n\to\infty}E(f({X_{n}}))=0$ which means that $X_{n}$ cannot converge in distribuiton to any random variable $X$ as if you choose $f=1$, then it means $E(f(X))=E(1)=0$. If you have not figured it out yet, this annomaly was due to $X_{n}$ not being a "Tight" sequence.
What's important in this problem is that you know that the joint cdf of $(X,Y)$ is actually a bonafide cdf (as (X,Y) are bonafide random variables). Thus it is sufficient that for all compactly supported functions, $E(f(X_{n},Y_{n}))\to E(f(X,Y))$. This will enable you to conclude that $F_{n}(x,y)\to F(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)$ which are continuity points of $F$.

Thank you. The hint for the equivalence given in the title was to use  Stone-Weierstrass and the fact that if $E[f(X_n)]\rightarrow E[f(X)]$ for any $f$ in a class of functions s.t. the family of all its linear combinations is dense in $C_0(\mathbf{R})$, then $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$. taking the latter for granted, isn't it working?

@Jack I have edited my answer to include the method using Stone-Weirestrass Theorem.

@Balajisb The swapping of the limit step does not even involve bump functions and is basic DCT as all the integrands are bounded and the two variate limit in $(m,n)$ exists so iterated limits must equal the same. It is the step in which we have to go from compactly supported functions to show the convergence of the joint cdf that we need bump functions. I had already stated in my answer that this is a sketch of the actual proof and not the whole proof and it is that step is the main complicated one and is too large to be included in the answer. If one wants, they can read from Billingsley.

@Mr.GandalfSauron I have posted another problem trying to use the hint I've mentioned. Could you take a look, please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4977695/c-0-mathbfr-otimes-c-0-mathbfr-is-dense-in-c-0-mathbfr2-with-re
